# connecting to Neo4j browser through Firefox

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling, graph-databases

I can easily connect to Neo4j enterprise edition browser with Google chrome with this URL : http://localhost:7474/browser/
but when I want to connect to the browser using Firefox , i get this error
[image]

in the password box  I type 'Neo4j'

Comment: Beware of capital letters... did you try 'neo4j'?

Comment: I wrote : neo4j

Comment: Since you have connected to Neo4j in your Chrome browser you have probably changed your password. So your password is not `neo4j` anymore.

Comment: I don't see why you could connect with Chrome and not with Firefox. Maybe you could check out the saved passwords on Chrome and check if you have the good one ?