# Neo4j: Can't log in: Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure

Tags: neo4j

When I do `:server connect` with `neo4j` and `neo4j` I get `Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.`.

I tried uncommenting the line `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` in `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` and restarting, but it still asks me to log in and still denies the login.

I can get in with `/usr/bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p neo4j`

I tried `/usr/bin/neo4j-admin set-initial-password secret` but it says `command failed: The specified user 'neo4j' already exists.`

I tried `sudo rm /var/lib/neo4j/data/dbms/auth` and restarting, but it gives the same result.

ubuntu 16.04

Installed with `sudo apt-get install neo4j=1:3.5.0`

Comment: A tar of 3.4.10 running in my local directory worked just fine. Who knows.

Comment: I had the same problem because i didn't change the password of neo4j user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I tried to set the initial password and it said `The specified user 'neo4j' already exists.` I had thought I had set the initial password earlier via the command line, but it didn't take because there were special characters in the password string.

What ended up working for me was opening up the Neo4j Browser and it prompted me for a password. I entered 'neo4j' and then it gave me the option to set a new password through the browser. Once I did that, it worked.

If you need to turn off `auth_enabled` to test something, make sure to remember to restart the server. `sudo neo4j restart` It can also take a few minutes to restart, so make sure it's fully up and running first. (And then, of course, don't forget to turn `auth_enabled` back on again.)

It also took me a few tries to get the configuration correct in the conf file at `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf`

I set `dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0`

And `dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=your.webdomain.com`

Also, this guide helped me with setting up a certificate for the neo4j browser endpoint. https://medium.com/neo4j/getting-certificates-for-neo4j-with-letsencrypt-a8d05c415bbd

Comment: For me, the problem was that I installed neo4j but I forgot to change the neo4j password in cypher-cli

Answer (score 2):

I disabled/uncomment authenitication in  /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf

To disable authentication, uncomment this line

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

**it worked for me.**

Make sure to comment it back when you are done for security purposes

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, a quick solution without any major changes to my local DB.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue with the initial setup. Kept getting the same unauthorised message. The issue with me was I was trying to access it in firefox. Tried in Chrome and it worked and prompted me to change my password. Found one issue stating this:
< [connecting to Neo4j browser through Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669899/connecting-to-neo4j-browser-through-firefox) >

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a long time and was able to fix it by setting a new password using the method described [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/password-and-user-recovery/#password-recovery-for-admin).

Answer (score 0):

You may see this issue after upgrading neo4j from version 4 to version 5, if you use the `set-initial-password` option.

The version 4 syntax is:

```
neo4j-admin set-initial-password secret
```

The version 5 syntax is:

```
neo4j-admin dbms set-initial-password secret
```

If the command does not run successfully, the admin user will not be able to authenticate.